# Upgrade Alert is showing continuously after I navigate to different screens in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `upgrader` package to show alert to user if a new version of app is available on playstore. But, after using it on a screen, it is appearing multiple times throughout the app. How can I fix this?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Upgrader().clearSavedSettings();
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        body: UpgradeAlert(
          debugLogging: true,
          child: ShowCaseWidget(
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use it in the `build` method because assume this: Whenever the widget is rebuilded - `Upgrader().clearSavedSettings();` will be called.
Utilize this functions using methods below:

1. Call it in `initState` of your State. Then it will be called whenever your widget's state is created.
2. If you want to call this method continiously - create stream with `Stream.periodic` inside the `initState` of your root widget's state.